# Jupyter notebook keeps asking to choose application to open .py file while using Conda install?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have recently run into a problem where running conda install in Jupyter notebook opens the prompt to choose an application to open '.py' files.
On the other hand, pip install continues to work fine.
Running conda install command from anaconda prompt also works fine and I guess the issue is restricted to Jupyter notebook.
I had recently updated the Anaconda Navigator and used VS code for coding but not sure whether either of these is related to this problem.
Has anyone ever faced this before? Please help me find a solution.

OS : Windows 10

[image: Please see the screenshot here..]

Comment: Uh, what happens if you choose `Python` in the dialog ?

Comment: Is that a regular Python code cell?

Comment: Nothing happens but the line is executed and returns with the message "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."